# YOLOV5 running on mac

Tags: macos, performance, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, yolov5

I have configured the environment to run on the new Metal Performance Shaders (MPS) backend for GPU training acceleration for PyTorch and when running Yolov5 on my Macbook M2 Air it is always creating an error.

```
RES_DIR = set_res_dir()
    if TRAIN:
        !python /Users/krishpatel/yolov5/train.py --data /Users/krishpatel/yolov5/roboflow/data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt \
        --img 640 --epochs {EPOCHS} --batch-size 32 --device mps  --name {RES_DIR}
```

this is the error

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mNR0.png)

```
UserWarning: The operator 'aten::nonzero' is not currently supported on the MPS backend and will fall back to run on the CPU. This may have performance implications. (Triggered internally at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/mps/MPSFallback.mm:11.)
  t = t[j]  # filter
  0%|          | 0/20 [00:16<?, ?it/s]                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/krishpatel/yolov5/train.py", line 630, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "/Users/krishpatel/yolov5/train.py", line 524, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "/Users/krishpatel/yolov5/train.py", line 307, in train
    loss, loss_items = compute_loss(pred, targets.to(device))  # loss scaled by batch_size
  File "/Users/krishpatel/yolov5/utils/loss.py", line 125, in __call__
    tcls, tbox, indices, anchors = self.build_targets(p, targets)  # targets
  File "/Users/krishpatel/yolov5/utils/loss.py", line 213, in build_targets
    j, k = ((gxy % 1 < g) & (gxy > 1)).T
NotImplementedError: The operator 'aten::remainder.Tensor_out' is not currently implemented for the MPS device. If you want this op to be added in priority during the prototype phase of this feature, please comment on https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/77764. As a temporary fix, you can set the environment variable `PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK=1` to use the CPU as a fallback for this op. WARNING: this will be slower than running natively on MPS.
```

what should i do? because when running in just cpu it is taking a very very very long time? any suggestions would be appreciated.

So I tried to search everywhere but couldn't find anything for macbook. I think if it doesn't help i would have to run it on google colab but then what would be the point of buying expensive macbook and not use gpu for running.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before, because your pytorch isn't nightly. Just download nightly and reconfigure your environment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).